# How to compare sales from an array and get the highest and lowest selling

Tags: java, arrays, compare

Does anybody have the code to be able to be able to compare the sales, or a variable, from an array, and be able to print out the highest and lowest selling items. I have tried several things but cant exactly get it to work.

Here is my code, the stuff I am most concerned about is at the bottom:

```
package album;

public class Certifier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

Album zero = new Album(0, "Dark Side of the Moon", "Pink Floyd", 1973, 50000000);

        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 0 is: " + zero.toString());

        Album one = new Album(1, "Superficial", "Heidi Montag",  2010, 658);

        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 1 is: " + one.toString());

        Album two = new Album(2, "Fearless", "Taylor Swift", 2011, 3200000);

        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 2 is: " + two.toString());

        Album three = new Album(3, "Made Up", "Sample Band", 2011, 1300000);

        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 3 is: " + three.toString());

        Album four = new Album(4, "Concerto One Night", "Andrea Bocelli", 2011, 500008);

        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 4 is: " + four.toString());

        Album[] albums = new Album[4];
            albums[0] = zero;
            albums[1] = one;
            albums[2] = two;
            albums[3] = three;
            albums[4] = four;


            ((Comparable<String>) albums[0]).compareTo(albums[1]);

        System.out.println("The highest selling album is");
        for (int i=0; i< Album[].length; i++) {
            double highestSales;
            if (i.getSales()<highestSales)
                highestSales= i;
            return highestSales;

        }

    System.out.println("The lowest selling album is");
        for (int i=0; i< Album[].length; i++) {
            double lowestSales;
            if (i.getSales()<lowestSales)
                lowestSales= i.getSales();
            return i.getName + i.getArtist;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to get the code to compile before posting it here.  For example, in your for loops `i` is an `int` not an object. You can't call a method on it.  Follow the compiler errors to get it to compile, then you'll be able to start working on the logic errors.

Comment: Scan through and find the highest and lowest values perhaps?

Comment: But you have to set lowest and highest to some value to start with.  Generally set highest to a negative number and lowest to a very large number.  (Or just initialize both from the zeroth element.)

Comment: (But the highest and lowest values need to be OUTSIDE the loops (of which you only need one).)

Answer (score 0):

```
Album highestSellingAlbum;
double highestSales = 0;

for (int i=0; i< albums.length; i++) 
{
  if (albums[i].getSales() > highestSales)
  {
    highestSales = albums[i].getSales();
    highestSellingAlbum = albums[i];
  }
}
```

`highestSellingAlbum` will now contain the highest selling album, assuming that your `Album` class has a proper `getSales()` method that returns the sales.

Answer (score 0):

to get `lowestSales` ever set you need to initialize it with a higher value as the real lowest that you look for. that could be `Double.MAX_VALUE` or the highestSale that you found before (assuming you fix the bug). You also should initialize highestSale of course, maybe with 0.0.

The fix for highestSale would be to assign `highestSales = i.getSales()` in your loop;

Comment: Im just looking for the highest and lowest sales out of the 5 options i have in the code

Comment: my suggestion would find exactly that, the highest and the lowest sales as values. If you need the information which album it came from, then use Grammin's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

here is a full and working version:

```
package album;


public class Certifier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Album zero = new Album(0, "Dark Side of the Moon", "Pink Floyd", 1973, 50000000);
        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 0 is: " + zero.toString());

        Album one = new Album(1, "Superficial", "Heidi Montag",  2010, 658);
        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 1 is: " + one.toString());

        Album two = new Album(2, "Fearless", "Taylor Swift", 2011, 3200000);
        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 2 is: " + two.toString());

        Album three = new Album(3, "Made Up", "Sample Band", 2011, 1300000);
        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 3 is: " + three.toString());

        Album four = new Album(4, "Concerto One Night", "Andrea Bocelli", 2011, 500008);
        System.out.println("The album information for ablum 4 is: " + four.toString());

        Album[] albums = new Album[5]; //we have 5 albums!
            albums[0] = zero;
            albums[1] = one;
            albums[2] = two;
            albums[3] = three;
            albums[4] = four;

        Album highestSellingAlbum = zero; //must be initialized with any of the 5
        Album lowestSellingAlbum = zero; //must be initialized with any of the 5

        for (int i=0; i< albums.length; i++) {

            if (albums[i].getSales() > highestSellingAlbum.getSales()){
                highestSellingAlbum = albums[i];
            }
            if (albums[i].getSales() < lowestSellingAlbum.getSales()){
                lowestSellingAlbum = albums[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The highest selling album is " + highestSellingAlbum);
        System.out.println("The highest sales is " + highestSellingAlbum.getSales() ); 

        System.out.println("The lowest selling album is " + lowestSellingAlbum);
        System.out.println("The lowest sales is " + lowestSellingAlbum.getSales() );

    }

}
```

There were numerous errors in your posted version, including compiling errors. You should start using an IDE like eclipse for your java experiments, because such environments show you your errors while programming.

To the algorithmic problem of yours. The key point is, that you need to initialize the variables against which you compare. I guess that is what you tried with that line `((Comparable<String>) albums[0]).compareTo(albums[1]);` in your code? Well, that line made no sense. Also, you were mixing the index of the array of Albums with the sales value of the albums. Well, have a look at my solution and study it. In future, please post only code that at least has no compilation errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can Implement Comparable Interface in Album class if you can change it and the simply call  `Arrays.sort(albums)`, it will short your array you can use first and last element of array as lowest and highest selling albums respectively.

Code will be some thing like this

```
public class Album implements Comparable<Album>{
     /*
      your existing code here
     */
     public int compareTo(Album compareAlbum) {
       int compareSales = ((Album) compareAlbum).getSales(); 
       return this.sales - compareSales
     }
}
```

If you can't change Album class then Grammin's answer is ok.

Comment: I think I can change the album class since I wrote it, since it basically has my setters and getters in it.